# Reference request on Idealist ontology

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, ontology, idealism

Apologies if this is original, it may or may not already exist (I've no idea), but it may also be a restatement of an ontology like [Meinong's jungle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexius_Meinong#Work). It contemplates a conception of concentric spheres of *mental* activity. While it immediately sounds like some form of idealism, note it may readily apply to the mental side of Dualism and so too a psychological aspect within Materialism. Here are the domains *(note their order of preeminence may be adjusted to suite the philosophic paradigms above)*:

**Creative:** This domain brings **new things** into the world. It has some alignment with Kant's [*a priori*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori), but note: *not [synthetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic%E2%80%93synthetic_distinction).* From Meinong's ontology it's closest association is with "Absistence"(Gegebenheit), but not square-circles(etc.) since those are syncretic. As it relates to conscious thinking: we don't very much here, it is the "zone", we *do* rather than think.

**Reflective/Theoretical:** This is the "real" thinking place, we are aware of awareness, it is [sapience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom#Sapience). Here we contemplate experience, *synthesize*, organize, name things real or abstract, (someone even made a square-circle). It is Meinong's "Subsistence"(Bestand) but also a bit of "Absistence" and, some say, it also "Exist". It takes input from both Creative and Concrete, thus it is most of all Kant's *a posteriori*.

**Empiric/Concrete:** This is what we find and leave behind, that which persist. Meinong's "Existence". For Kant it is what comes before the posterior... We *do* think here but not with self-awareness, this is mostly [sentience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentience).

---

**Question:** Is there an ontology resembling the above?

Comment: Very generally you may want to know something of JN Findlay’s journey. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/findlay/index.html

Comment: This remidns me not so much an ontology as [Bloom's taxonomy of cognitive skills](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4511057/) used in education.

Comment: It appears to take the existence of empirical objects as a given and to say nothing about ontology except to endorse Realism. .  . .

Comment: @PeterJ Empirical objects are _persistent_, that is _the_ observer gives way to _an_ observer.